# Creating a structure in array in the batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm learning batch script, i came across a section **creating structure in array**. This is the sample program given as example.When i try to execute, It is not working. Can someone explain me what is wrong script?
Thanks in advance!

**code:**

```
@echo off
set len=3
set obj[0].name=Joe
set obj[0].id=1
set obj[1].name=Mark
set obj[1].id=2
set obj[2].name=mohan
set obj[2].id=3
set i=0
:loop
if %i% equ %len% goto :eof
set cur.name=
set cur.id=
for /f "usebackq delims==. tokens=1-3" %%j in ('set obj[%i%]') do (
    set cur.%%k=%%l 
)
echo name=%cur.name%
echo value=%cur.id%
set /a i=%i%+1
goto loop
```

Comment: _"it is not working"_ in not a valid problem description.

Comment: Gerhard Barnard The problem is while printing name and value only 
name=  and value = is printed the actual value for the name and value is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "usebackq delims==. tokens=1-3" %%j in ('set obj[%i%]') do (
```

is wrong. There are two sorts of single quotes:

Either use the correct quotes ' (without `usebackq`):

```
for /f "delims==. tokens=1-3" %%j in ('set obj[%i%]') do (
```

or with `usebackq` use the `  quotes

```
for /f "usebackq delims==. tokens=1-3" %%j in (`set obj[%i%]`) do (
```